# Is `id_token_signing_alg_values_supported` administrated by Microsoft or the tenant's administrators?

Tags: azure, entra-id, microsoft, oidc

I have created a custom OIDC authorizer for a AWS API Gateway (REST). It currently support tokens signed using the RS256 algorithm, and will otherwise fail.

The `.well-known` OIDC endpoint lists the following supported algorithms, so everything is OK:

`"id_token_signing_alg_values_supported":["RS256"]`

https://login.microsoftonline.com/1d063515-6cad-4195-9486-ea65df456faa/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration

Is `id_token_signing_alg_values_supported` administrated by Microsoft or the tenant's administrators? If Microsoft, where can I find information on when it will change?